# LM7805 outputting ~2.5v

Tags: arduino, power-supply, voltage-regulator

I tried building a basic power supply on my breadboard using the schematic for SparkFun's Breadboard Power Supply (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8376).

My setup is:

- Hooked up 10uF capacitor to VIN and GND
- Hooked up 0.1uF capacitor to VOUT and GND
- Hooked up GND and VOUT to the voltage rails on the breadboard
- Hooked up Arduino UNO's 5v and GND pins to voltage rails

A Fritzing diagram is here: http://www.chris-cartwright.com/BadReg.fzz

This setup works fine without the Arduino load. Once the Arduino is connected, the voltage drops down to about 2.5v.

I'm not sure what is wrong with the circuit. My load readings are about 17mA.

I do not have access to an oscilloscope to check the circuit with, but I  don't think oscillation is my issue given how similar my circuit is.

Comment: `File` | `Export` | `as Image` | `PNG...`

Comment: **ctrl-m** to draw schematic when editing post

Comment: Without a schematic, or at least a diagram that is readable (though a schematic is worlds better) there really is no way to answer this question.

Comment: The [SparkFun board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8376), which is used as a reference design by the O.P, is made with LM340.  The title of the question deals with LM7805.  That's odd.

Comment: Your Frizting diagram shows a 9V battery are you using a decent quality Alkaline and do you know it's OK? Most 9V batteries can't deliver much current.

Comment: While I have no problem with fritzing being used, you should post it as an image so others can see. And @echad only people with enough rep (10 I think) can use the schematic editor, just fyi

Comment: Chris, do you have the resistors R1 and R2 as well?

Comment: Chris, what is the input power source to the regulator?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I am using the 7805. I was using the SFE circuit for reference. My setup is exactly the same as the Fritzing diagram I linked to.

Comment: @Passerby I'll post an image of the schematic or edit the post when I get home tonight.

Comment: @PeterJ I haven't tried with a more powerful pack yet. I'll try something bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PeterJ's response to my question had the answer: [LM7805 outputting ~2.5v](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76925/lm7805-outputting-2-5v#comment149580_76925)

My battery was dying/dead. A new 9v battery solved the problem.

Comment: If you solved it, you should mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have to wait another 13 hours before I can select it.

Comment: You probably don't want to power such a circuit even off  a **new** 9v battery.  It won't last long, as it is highly inefficient, turning approximately as much energy into heat as it delivers.

Answer (score 1):

Several points of confusion.
The SFE project is using a LM317, that is adjustable, and requires the R1 R2 feedback. A LM7805 does not require the resistors. The circuit is correct as drawn for a 7805.

Also not that the UNO has a regulator on board to do just this. You can connect the 9V Battery to GND and Vin. The on board MC33269 (or similar NCP1117) will provide about 200 mA at 9V, without over heating. As per this [quick reference](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/QuickRef).

If you really had an ADJUST 7800-ADJ or LM317-ADJ, then the missing R1,R2 would explain your observation.

Comment: +1 for the useful, albeit cluttered, quick reference link! :-)

Comment: I didn't want to use the on-board regulator because I'll be switching to the Arduino Pro running two servos. I'm planning on hooking up VIN to both Arduino and regulator to the power source (battery pack)